# How can "Sign up with Facebook" on some website include my name and even my profile picture?

Tags: privacy, anonymity, facebook

I just got into a website registration page and saw there was a "Sign Up with Facebook" button, which showed my profile pic and name.

How does it do that?
Does that mean the website has my name and profile picture as well?

Comment: Try to turn off the cookies and scripts with uMatrix. Then it should no longer contain your name.

Comment: the info is from facebook.  The site you are visiting does not have access to it.  See this for more info:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/